# Dynamically building a whereHas constraint

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have the following **whereHas** constraint:

```
$query->whereHas('club', function($q)
{
    $q->whereHas('membership', function($q)
    {
        $q->whereHas('package', function($q)
        {
            $q->whereId(Input::get('package_id'));
        });
    });
});
```

I would like to build the above from an input as such:

`['key' => 'package_id', 'relationship' => 'club.membership.package']`

Is this possible?

I don't know in this case how to properly explode and iterate `relationship` from the array.

Comment: Check PR https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4237 as it solves the problem

Comment: @deczo Please convert your comment to an answer, as I merged manually and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check PR github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4237 as it solves the problem.

**Update:** The mentioned PR has moved to github.com/laravel/framework/pull/6726 and is now merged.

Comment: Great work Mr. deczo. Now I can finally be at peace building filters.